# 2d array of pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers

Why doesn't this code work at making a 2D array pointers in c++? The compiler complains about the second line not being a modifiable l-value.

```
      int* g[2][2];
  g[0] = new (int*)[2];
```

Comment: are you trying to allocating memory for `g`???

Comment: no i just want an array of arrays of pointer to int.

Comment: @SamAdams: You already have that after the first line.  What's the intent of the second line?

Comment: just trying to learn c++ so i guess the second line is useless and the 2d array is already initialized after the first line.

Comment: @SamAdams not initialized but rather allocated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `g[0]` is `int* [2]`, i.e. it's an array.  You cannot assign to an array.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, so I can't offer a solution.  If you clarify your question, I may be able to do better.

Answer (score 3):

The first line is all you need to create an array of 2 arrays of pointers to `int`.

The reason you can't assign a new value to `g[0]` is because `g[0]` itself is an array, and you can't assign a new value to an array, only its elements.